# 2002 - Сервер не отвечает (либо локальный сокет сервера MySQL неверно настроен)

Tags: mysql

Как исправить ошибку MySQL ?

Здравствуйте всем, работая на `Denwer` в `phpMyAdmin` по неопытности что то удалил, сейчас входя в `phpMyAdmin` пишет - Ответ `MySQL`: Документация

```
#2002 - Сервер не отвечает (либо локальный сокет сервера `MySQL` неверно настроен).
```

Удалять `Denwer` и ставить по новому, не помогает, смена браузере - не дает не чего. Кто подскажет - ,,где собака зарыта,, ? День лазил по форумам, такие вопросы встречал, много, но ответов решить проблему не нашел.

Comment: Хотелось бы сперва, спросить, у вас mysql сервер запущен ? Если запустили, тогда посмотрите, что пишет error_log,+ к этому my.ini(my.cnf). В файле конфигураций конкретно указывайте путь к socket,pid файлам.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь порты, где запускается денвер